# If $k|n, k \geq 2$, then $D_{n}$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $D_{k}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Restatement of question: If $k|n, k \geq 2$, then the group $D_{n}$ has a subgroup isomorphic to the group $D_{k}$.

My attempt at proving the result stated:

Let us say that $D_{n}= \{1, \sigma, \sigma^{2}, ..., \sigma^{n-1}, \tau, \tau \sigma, \tau \sigma^{2}, ..., \tau \sigma^{n-1} \}$. As $k|n$, and $< \sigma >$ is a subgroup of $D_{n}$ of order n, then by the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Cyclic Groups, $< \sigma^{\frac{n}{k}} >$ is a subgroup of order $k$. Now I am stuck on how to show that there exists a subgroup $A$ of $D_{n}$, where $A= \{< \sigma^{\frac{n}{k}} >, $k number of other elements$ \}$ $\cong D_{k}$. I am not entirely sure how to proceed from here.

I thank you in advance for taking the time to inspect my work!

Comment: Show that $<\tau, \sigma^{\frac{n}{d}}>$ has $2k$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the subgroup $\langle \sigma^{n/k},\tau\rangle$ of $D_n$ generated by $\sigma^{n/k}$ and $\tau$. Suppose $D_k = \langle \sigma_k,\tau_k\rangle$ with the usual relations.

Define a map $\phi : D_k\rightarrow D_n$ by $\sigma_k\mapsto \sigma^{n/k}$, $\tau_k\mapsto\tau$.

By checking that $\sigma^{n/k},\tau$ satisfy the relations defining $D_k$, we find that $\phi$ extends to a homomorphism. It clearly surjects onto the subgroup $\langle \sigma^{n/k},\tau\rangle\subset D_n$.

Noting that every element of $D_k$ can be written as $\sigma_k^a\tau_k^b$ for some integers $a,b$, it's easy to prove that $\phi$ is injective. Alternatively, to complete the proof of bijectivity of $\phi$ (onto $\langle \sigma^{n/k},\tau\rangle$), you can argue that $\langle \sigma^{n/k},\tau\rangle\subset D_n$ has the same number of elements as $D_k$.

This is an example of a general method of proving two things are isomorphic - come up with a map, show it's a homomorphism, prove that it's injective and surjective.

Comment: Ah, right. The proof is pretty obvious now by defining the mapping from $D_{k}$ to $D_{n}$. I suppose I was trying to figure out the mapping from $< \sigma^{n/k},\tau >$ to $D_{k}$ without success. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. As you say, $\sigma^{n/k}$ is a rotation of order $k$ in $D_n$. To finish, you just need to argue that the subgroup $
\langle \sigma^{n/k},\tau \rangle$ is isomorphic to $D_k$. The easiest way to do this is to show that $\sigma^{n/k}$ and $\tau$ satisfy the usual generating relations for $D_k$: $(\sigma^{n/k})^k=\tau^2=1$, and $\tau \sigma^{n/k}\tau^{-1}=\sigma^{-n/k}$. I'll leave the verification of these equalities to you.